# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, jquery-select2

I'm having the following tag field in my form for creating tags in a blog post,since blog tags can be multiple related to a single post, I'v uses select2 for that and here is the input field I'v used:

```
 {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') }}
      <select name="tags[]" class="form-control select2-multi" multiple="multiple">
          @foreach($tags as $tag)
             <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
```

**This is the function where the data goes for validation and then store into the database**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //   --------       WORKFLOW  HERE  ------
        // validate the data from the form
        $this->validate($request,array(

                'title'       => 'required|max:255',
                'slug '       => '|min:5|alpha_dash|max:255|unique:posts,slug|',
                'category_id' => 'required|integer',
                'body'        => 'required'

        ));  // end of validation

        // sotre that data into database
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title        = $request->title;
        $post->slug         = $request->slug;
        $post->category_id  = $request->category_id;
        $post->body         = $request->body;

        $post->save();
        $post->tags()->sync('$request->tags',false);

        Session::flash('success','Your Post has been Successful saved !');
        // and then redirect the user to some page
        return redirect()->route('posts.show',$post->id);


    }
```

**Getting the following error while trying to save the post**

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()`

**Tag** Model

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function post(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
   }
}
```

**Table structure** of `post_tag`

[image]

Comment: have you defined the relationship `tags` ?

Comment: have you initialised your tags relationship

Comment: well I guess No, how to do that? @MayuriPansuriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you post model add this

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::class,'id','post_id');
}
```

Comment: it says:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `post_tag` (`post_id`, `tag_id`) values (20, 1))  ,

Comment: share your tag model an table structure

Comment: class Tag extends Model
{
    public function post(){
     
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}

Comment: Please see the table structure , I'v updated the post @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: have you set id as auto increment and primary key in table

Comment: I got this, actually the AI was unchecked Thank you @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: thanks and happy to help also accept the answer so others can get help from this